# Python Requests gives different page text than Internet Explorer

Tags: python, internet-explorer, python-requests

Looking at my stackoverflow user profile page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683104/roberto

The site indicates I have been a member for 316 days (screenshots at end of post). If I `view source` in my browser (IE11), I can see this data comes from a `days-visited` class.

But if I look for this same `days-visited` information using Python Requests, the data does not appear anywhere. Why?

```
from requests import Session
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

s = Session()

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683104/roberto'
page = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
print soup.prettify() #server response, prettified

# following returns error
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
#days_visited = soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'days-visited'}).getText()

s.close()
```

**screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

**view source**
[image: view_source]

**python Requests**
[image: python_requests]

Comment: Try configuring the user agent?

Comment: Because "days-visited" only shows when you logged-in, while python-requests only getting the public version of the your profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field is not visible to your script (or other users). If you want to scrap that piece of information, you will need to have your script login and store appropriate cookies.

This is what is seen by users that aren't you:
[image: Profile]

And the code block they see:

```
 <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>visits</th>
                <td>member for</td>

                <td class="cool" title="2013-08-14 15:38:01Z">11 months</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td>seen</td>

                <td class="supernova" title="2014-08-08 05:26:50Z">
                    <span title="2014-08-08 05:26:50Z" class="relativetime">6 mins ago</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Normally, I'd recommend against scraping Stack Overflow for data and use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) instead, but this particular piece of information isn't returned as part of the [User](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) object.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments said, 'days-visited' only shows when you are logged-in. And it can be seen only by the member himself.

You may find you cookies in your browser and use cookies in you request.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies